# I'm trying to replace a component on a circuit board. Is this a fuse?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, fuses

This smd component has shorted. I'm assuming it is a fuse, but I don't understand what the 4 over the underscore means, if it is even a "4". Does somebody know what this component is and how to interpret the labels?
[image: Shorted Component]

Answer (score 2):

If it's a fuse, and it's still good, then it should be shorted (multimeter rings in continuity mode between pins). It will only open if it blows.

That looks like a [polyswitch](https://www.digikey.fr/fr/products/filter/fusibles-ctp-r%C3%A9armables/150) (self resettable PTC thermal fuse). The resistance of these increases to a high value when they get hot, which limits current, then returns to a very low resistance when cooling down, so it can "blow" then reset multiple times without having to be replaced.

You can measure voltage across it with the device powered. It should be pretty low, maybe in the tens of millivolts. If it got the full power supply voltage across it, then it has opened. This either means it's dead (unlikely) or there is a short downstream that draws enough current to make it do its job.

[image]